# How to check null while joining multiple tables by LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

```
var Data = (from s in _context.PRD_RecipeItem.AsEnumerable()
            where s.RecipeID == _RecipeID
            from i in _context.Sys_ChemicalItem.Where(x => x.ItemID == s.ItemID).DefaultIfEmpty()
            from u in _context.Sys_Unit.Where(x => x.UnitID == s.UnitID).DefaultIfEmpty()
            from st in FinalStock.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.ItemID == s.ItemID).DefaultIfEmpty()
            from sup in _context.Sys_Supplier.Where(x => x.SupplierID == (st==null? 0: st.SupplierID)).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new PRDChemProdReqItem
            {
                ItemID = s.ItemID,
                ItemName = (i == null ? null : i.ItemName),
                RequiredQty = s.RequiredQty,
                RequiredUnit = s.UnitID,
                RequiredUnitName = (u == null ? null : u.UnitName),
                RequsitionQty = s.RequiredQty,
                ApproveQty = s.RequiredQty,
                ApproveUnit = s.UnitID,
                ApproveUnitName = (u == null ? null : u.UnitName),
                PackSizeName = "",
                PackQty = 0,
                SizeUnitName = "",
                RequisitionUnit = s.UnitID,
                RequisitionUnitName = (u == null ? null : u.UnitName),
                StockQty = (st == null ? null : (Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(st.ClosingQty), 2)).ToString()),
                SupplierID = (st == null ? 0 : st.SupplierID),
                SupplierName = (sup == null ? null : sup.SupplierName),
                ItemSource = "Via Requisition"
            }).ToList();
```

This is my code. When `st` is `null`, then I'm getting An exception of type `System.Reflection.TargetException`. How to solve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @har07 how to stress those words? I would like to do that next time. Thanks.

Comment: wrap the words with backticks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx)? This will take care of your null values.

See more details including source code here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx